# Why does calling kernel32.GetModuleHandleA() for msvcr100 fail in Python?

Tags: python, winapi

I am having a problem with calling `GetModuleHandleA()` using Python. I have a module that attaches as debugger to the process. I'm working on a function that would return address of the function in the specific DLL module.  `GetModuleHandleA("msvcr100")` fails all of the time.

```
from ctypes import *
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
```

Function declared as part of a bigger **debug** class. That's the part of function declaration:

```
   def resolve_function(self,dll,function): 
        handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll)
        if handle == False:
            print "kernel32.GetModuleNameA() failed!!!"
            return False
        address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, function)
        if address == False:
            print "kernel32.GetProcAddress() failed!!!"
            return False
        kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
        return address
```

Call the function made as:

```
function_address = debug.resolve_function("msvcr100", "printf")
```

I run separate process that uses printf() and then attach to it. Everything works fine until I get to GetModuleHandleA() that returns **False** all of the time.

Code that runs printf():

```
from ctypes import *
import time
msvcr100 = cdll.msvcr100
counter = 0
while 1:
    msvcr100.printf("Counter = %d\n" % counter)
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that msvcr100 is actually loaded into the process? `GetModuleHandle()` doesn't actually do any loading itself...

Comment: And, uh... You might find this useful: [How to *printf* in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-printf-in-python/493500#493500)

Comment: I have. It does load msvcr100.dll, because it prints stuff on the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You've found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834762/why-does-calling-kernel32-getmodulehandlea-for-msvcr100-fail-in-python/4835791#4835791) to your problem, but I'm answering anyway to explain why your original effort failed (and why your fix worked).

First, msvcrt/msvcr100 are **two different versions** of Microsoft's C runtime library. There are other versions as well, and all of them contain their own definitions for `printf()`. A given process may have any one of them loaded, or multiple versions loaded, or *no* versions loaded - it's possible to produce console output [using only WinAPI functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073.aspx)! In short, if it's not your process, you can't depend on *any* given version of the C runtime being available.

Second, **[`GetModuleHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199.aspx) doesn't *load* anything**. It returns a handle to the named module *only if* it has already been loaded. msvcr100.dll can be sitting *right there* on disk, but if the process hasn't already loaded it then GetModuleHandle won't give a handle to you. [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175.aspx) is the function you'd call if you wanted to both load *and* retrieve a handle to a named module... But you *probably* don't want to do this in a process you don't own.

FWIW, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is a handy tool for viewing the DLLs already loaded by a process.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The question is: if i call printf() in a script as msvcr100 = cdll.msvcr100, msvcr100.printf("Counter = %d\n" % counter). Isn't it supposed to load msvcr100.dll and then call printf() out of msvcr100?

Comment: @PSS: I'm not really familiar with CDLL, but that looks plausible... You can double-check it using Process Explorer if you want. But as I mentioned, you probably don't want to load a different version of the runtime library dynamically if you can help it: there's a really good chance that it won't get initialized properly, and *things won't work*. Remember, this is a runtime library, not a grab-bag of utility functions. Is there a reason you're not using Python's built-in printing routines?

Comment: I'm learning how to attach and debug process using python. I don't really have to use printf() and python. I've created executable with C++ that uses printf()...I could use some other function...the reason for it is that i'm trying to get an address of that function so I could set a breakpoint later in my code. And printf() was my choice to experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying:

```
...
```

handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(dll)
        if handle == False:
            error = GetLastError()
            print "ERROR: %d - %s" % (error, FormatError(error))
            return False

...

I get: **ERROR: 126 - The specified module could not be found**

I actually replaced msvcr100.dll with msvcrt.dll in my code and it worked perfect. I found out that msvcrt.dll is system dll. msvcr100.dll ships with Studio 2010. They are both located in C:\Windows\system32. It is still a mystery for me why msvcr100.dll did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetLastError()` (or `WinError`) from `ctypes` to find out why you're getting a NULL return, then add that information to your error message.  Even after you figure out this specific problem, you'll want that more robust error reporting.

See the ctypes docs for details:  http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

Comment: I get: ERROR: 126 - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: if I use msvcrt.dll instead of msvcr100.dll everything works as it supposed to...I am confused. Both dlls are in system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
msvcr100 = cdll.msvcr100
```

before calling:

```
function_address = debug.resolve_function("msvcr100", "printf")
```

to make sure the DLL is loaded in your process. `msvcrt` might work because it was already loaded.

Comment: debug.resolve_function() is in the module that hooks up to process that loads msvcr100 and uses printf() out of it. I know it works because I can see it print stuff out.